# ¿Se tiene pensado implementar emmet en el Code Snippet?

Tags: característica-nueva

La funcionalidad de insertar fragmentos de código (Code Snippet) `JavaScript/HTML/CSS/` de por si es ya bastante útil, mi pregunta en si es esa; 
 *¿Se tiene pensado implementar [emmet](http://emmet.io/) en el Code Snippet?* 
Lo pregunto porque sin duda sería un plus gigante como lo tienen en otros editores online tales como [codepen](http://codepen.io), [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) y [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit) (los qué son más conocidos al menos para mi pero estoy seguro que hay muchos más)

O al menos la característica de cerrar automáticamente tags (autoclose tags) como se tiene también en los anteriores editores online mencionados

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar en breves palabras que es emmet, en la pregunta, sin tener que ir al enlace? Creo que de este modo contribuiría a ampliar nuestra "cultura" informática. Yo mismo no sabía lo que era, ahora lo sé, pero tuve que ir al enlace y leer en inglés :)

Comment: Bienvenido al grupo de usuarios que quisieran que un sitio de programación como SO tenga un mejor editor de código. Todos nuestros operadores están ocupados en este momento, por favor aguarde en línea y tomaremos su pedido...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el meta.so hay una pregunta similar -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271897/emmet-in-stacksnippets

Fue publicada en el 2014, tiene varios comentarios pero ninguna respuesta, así que podría decirse que no hay una respuesta oficial al respecto, en otras palabras, quien sabe.